# How to get maximum ZIndex of all markers?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I need to get the maximum value of `zindex` of all markers to set firs and the las on the top, so i do it like this:

```
var max_marker_zindex = 0;

for (i = 1, len = map_coordinates.length - 1; i < len; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: map_coordinates[i],
        map: map
    });

    max_marker_zindex = marker.getZIndex() > max_marker_zindex ? marker.getZIndex() : max_marker_zindex;
}
```

But the problem is that `getZIndex` always returns null and there isn't any event for marker loading state.... How i can get the maximum index of markers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the zIndex-property is undefined unless you set it on your own.

use `google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX +  1` instead